# The database does not display the data in the table added via the JAVA program

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

I have a problem with the database, I have no idea what's going on. When I want to add data to the database, nothing happens, but when I add them via MySQL Workbench, usersid numbers (primary key) are occupied, but it does not show them in the table.

```
 void createConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        this.con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb",
                "root", "admin");
        System.out.println("Database is connected.");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BazaPodatakaVerzija1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BazaPodatakaVerzija1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

try {
        java.sql.Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO USERS(name, password, email) VALUES ('3dsdadsadfa', '34fd65652', 'fhjgjfgdh76')");

        // stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO USERS(name, password, email) VALUES ('" + ime_TF.getText() + "', '" + lozinka_TF.getText() + "', '" + email_TF.getText() +"')");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InterfejsGIO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Like (auto-)commit?

Comment: It looks like the result grid isn't showing the latest results, maybe because it's in editing mode. What happens when you click the refresh icon?

Comment: Nothing, I tried to refresh the screen, various things, but it still stands the same

Comment: If you select all rows from the Java code, does it return all expected results?